# java.lang.RuntimeException: Method isEmpty in android.text.TextUtils not mocked

Tags: android, mockito

loginUnit.java(Test file)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class loginUnit {
    @Mock
    TextUtils mMockTextUtils;

    @Test
    public void checkStringEmpty(){

        String empty = "";
        when(mMockTextUtils.isEmpty(empty)).thenReturn(true);
        assertThat(LoginActivity.isStringEmpty(empty),is(equalTo(true)));
    }
```

UUT(unit under test) from LoginActivity

```
public static boolean isStringEmpty(String s){
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(s);
}
```

I always get android.text.TextUtils not mocked error, please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your src/test/java folder, add android.text package and create TextUtils.java

```
public class TextUtils {
  public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
  }
}
```

Detail Here : https://medium.com/@okmanideep/dont-create-that-stringutils-to-unit-test-your-android-class-8ab32af34e84

Comment: Yes i can do that,  but i want to do using mockito.

Answer (score 6):

see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```